# Find and prove that a proper subset $A\subset \Bbb N$ such that $A\approx \Bbb N$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone check my working please?

> Find and prove that a proper subset $A\subset \Bbb N$ such that $A\approx \Bbb N$.

Let $A$ be the set of even numbers, it is clear that $A\subset \Bbb N$ since all even numbers are a member of $\Bbb N$, but $3\in \Bbb N$ is not in A.

$A\approx \Bbb N$ iff there is a bijection from $A$ to $\Bbb N$, ie. a function that is one-one and onto.

Let this function be $f:A→ \Bbb N$ such that $f(x)=x÷2$.

One-one: $f(x)=f(y)\to x=y$

According to the def. of $f$, this means $\frac x2=\frac y2\to x=y$. But if we times $x$ and $y$ in the antecedent by 2 we get $x=y\to x=y$, thus $f$ is one-one.

Onto: $\forall n\in \Bbb N \exists x\in A$ such that $ f(x)=n$

Assume $ f(x)\not=n$, this means there exists an $x$ such that dividing it by 2 does not give us a natural number - but that's impossible. Therefore $f$ is onto.

Comment: Your phrasing of the proof of surjectivity is wrong. There are many natural numbers such that dividing them by two does not give a natural number - namely, all odd natural numbers. Simply note that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the number $x=2n$ satisfies $f(x)=n$.  So $f$ is onto

Comment: I would change "if we times $x$ and $y$ ..." to "if we multiply each of $x$ and $y$ ...", because "times" is not a verb. The added "each" makes it clear that we're not saying to compute $xy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a good one, and the injectivity proof is good.

Surjectivity, on the other hand, is a bit off. Given an arbitrary $n\in\Bbb N$, you have to show that there is an $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=n$. Setting $x=2n$ works.